# Icon change on Desktop doesn't effect/apply

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

When I want to change the icon from a shortcut or folder on Desktop the change doesn't effect/apply on Desktop. When I navigate to `$HOME/Desktop` (`$HOME/Schreibtisch` in my way) the icon change effects but not on the Desktop itself.

OS version: 20.04 LTS

`gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` is installed.

Comment: I know that's why I installed `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`.

Comment: I just tested this myself. New icons on folders appear only if the folder is not on the Desktop proper. They do appear if the folder is anywhere else. It's because the `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` is a work-in-progress, and doesn't support ALL desktop icons yet.